# PHP echoing array with concatenation

Tags: php

Can you help me? I'm getting a little problem at my code.

```
$json = '{"data":{"id":1,"first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"}}';
$response = json_decode($json, true);

$output = ['data']['first_name'];
echo $response.$output;
```

Error: Array to string conversion on line number => `echo $response.$output;`

How can I solve this? I tried so much but without success.

Thank you.

Comment: `$output = $response['data']['first_name'];
echo $output;`

Comment: I know it, but the script was just an example. Because `$output` is not constant, it means that, sometimes `$output` might change

Comment: you have use to var_dump() because your response is in array format

Comment: So, that is right, isn't it? $output should be different each time depending on "first_name" value

Comment: No, I explained it wrong, sorry. Sometimes, `$output` can be `['data']['first_name']` or `['data']['last_name']`. Did you understand? `$output` can change.

Comment: _"it means that, sometimes $output might change"_ - How would it change? And how would your code know about that change?

Comment: here when you write $output = ['data']['first_name']; it means you are declaring $output as array... But your expecting ['data']['first_name'] this as a string & tring to concatenate with $response... for that you have to  convert ['data']['first_name'] to string & store in $output & echo $response.$output same as $response ['data']['first_name']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array keys are dynamic, then:

```
$key = 'first_name';
echo $response['data'][$key];
```

Even if `'data'` key can change then:

```
$firstKey = 'data';
$secondKey = 'first_name';
echo $response[$firstKey][$secondKey];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'first_name' or 'last_name' instead of ['data']['first_name']:

```
$json = '{"data":{"id":1,"first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"}}';
$response = json_decode($json, true);
$output = 'first_name'; //your flexible variable.. first_name or last_name
echo $response['data'][$output];
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use for concatenation

```
$json = '{"data":{"id":1,"first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"}}';
    $response = json_decode($json, true);


    $output = $response['data']['first_name'] ." " . $response['data']['last_name'];
    echo $output;
    die;
```

Answer (score 0):

$response is an array and echo doesn't know how to display arrays.

Use this instead :

```
foreach($response['data'] as $value) {
   echo $value.PHP_EOF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you:

```php
$json = '{"data":{"id":1,"first_name":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"}}';
$response = json_decode($json, true);

$output1 = "data";
$output2 = "first_name";
echo $response[$output1][$output2];
```